# vector of list. Should I use pointers or values?

Tags: data-structures, c++11, stl, hashtable

I am implementing the data struct **hash table** where collisions are resolved using chains.

So as **underlying data** structure I need **vector of lists**.
I choice from 2 variants:

- `std::vector<std::list<entry> >`
- `std::vector<std::list<entry>* >`

where entry is struct which contains data and hash value;

**Question:** will it be a huge decrease in the efficiency if I use first variant(question is considered on a large input data)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need to implement a hash table? C++11 has std::unordered_set and std::unordered_map (as well as their "multi" counterparts).

Comment: Yes, this is for an educational purpose.

Comment: Don't use a `std::list<entry>` unless you insert/remove elements from the middle of the list orders of magnitude more often than you iterate over it, or if `entry` is non-movable and expensive to copy, or expensive to move.  `std::list` is `std::`"bidirectional linked list", not `std::`"the ideal container to use when you want a list of things".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no advantage to using a pointer, and it adds the complication of needing to be deleted when you destroy the vector. Go ahead and use `vector<list<entry> >`. The `list` will be allocating memory for the elements anyway, but it will be invisible to you.

There might be a performance penalty if the vector has to be resized, but a C++11 compiler should use moves instead of copies to minimize it. And for a learning project the performance shouldn't be your first concern anyway.

Comment: I found very usefull information in your answer that STL container vector allocates memory in heap for it`s elements. That information made me to deduce that there will be subtle difference in 2 variants in case of efficiency and as 2-nd impose more work to be done(memory allocation/deallocation) I shall choice 1-st. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

The only real difference is that with the first method the entries in your buckets/chains will be stored on the stack, whereas the entries for the second method will be stored on the heap.  For large structures I've found that storing on the heap is usually better, but it's debatable.  Really, as long as you remember to new up the entries when you add them to the list, then you're fine.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. In both cases everything apart from the internals of the `std::vector` will always be allocated from the free-store.

Comment: When I read Mark Ransom answer I realized that in both variants chains(lists) will be stored in the stack due to vector implementation.

Comment: @spin_eight: No. std::vector always allocates its contents on the free store, and nothing in Mark's answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: -1. I think you're confusing contiguous storage with stack storage. Also, using raw pointers is a whole lot more involved than just new-ing up the entries. In fact, of all the problems that you'll have to deal with, "remembering" to new up the elements is the least of them, since the code won't even compile if you forget to. By contrast, the compiler won't complain at all if you forget to `delete` items once you're done with them, or if you copy the pointers to some other data structure and forget *not* to `delete` them when removing them from the vector.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos yes, sure I mistyped - ofcourse in heap, not in stack

Comment: @spin_eight: No probs. Btw, I just realised that it might not be obvious: my "-1" comment is directed at the answer, not your comment.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos I understod that it is directed to the answer. Thanks for pointing to my mistake.